# Is it fine to send a resume instead of a CV?

Tags: resume

I have both a resume and a European CV, and I see that some job offers explicitly ask for a resume, while some ask for a CV.

The fact is that in my case, my resume is much stronger than my CV. This happens because the European Curriculum has a strict format and I am using a specific template that allows little customization, while my resume is more customized and adapted to my needs.

I am looking for a job specially in Europe, in countries like (listed by importance) the Netherlands, the U.K., Germany and Scandinavian countries, but also Worldwide.

Now if some companies have a "CV" section in their application form, do you think that it would be okay to send my resume instead? or maybe this would be looked upon negatively by recruiters?

Comment: In Europe, the two words are generally interchangeable in most fields.

Comment: Here in the United States, either is acceptable.

Comment: Are you asking if it is OK to ignore the part of the online application form where it asks for your previous employment details and instead send a resume document?

Comment: No. I am asking if it's okay to attach a resume instead of a CV when asked explicitly for a CV.

Comment: What, exactly, do you consider a resume? What, exactly, do you consider a CV? How are they different?

Comment: A resume is usually a single page whereas a CV, at least in academia, is a more complete listing of your accomplishments--education, teaching experience, research, grants awarded, publications, etc. Depending on how much experience you have under your belt, it can be quite lengthy.

Comment: "`the European Curriculum has a strict format `" - only insomuch as every one is strictly different from every other. There is no DIN/ISO format for CVs (which, as stated, are in Europe just another word for resume (a word which almost no one in Europe uses, even if aware of it)).

Comment: I can't speak for all of Europe but I've worked in a couple of European countries. I'm aware that there is some pedantic difference between a resume and a CV but I think you'd be hard pressed to find any hiring person that knows the difference.

Comment: There is an EU Standard CV format (Europass) but in some countries and sectors it may be widely used; in others almost unknown. There are plenty of good online CV templates. You *must* tailor your CV/resume to the employer and also to the destination country. A UK CV will probably not be accepted in Germany, and a German CV will look decidedly odd in the UK.

Comment: In my work (software engineer in the Netherlands), I have never had to use the 'standard' European CV format (Europass), and I have never seen people using it. What is generally referred to as a CV is the same as a resume, and they come in broad range varying in scope, amount of details (breadth and depth), organization of information, etc. In my experience, in business (non-government, non-academia) a CV of 1 to 2 pages is considered normal, having more than 3 pages will raise eyebrows.

Answer (score 11):

I'm from the UK.

So far as I'm aware, we consider them to be different words **for the same thing**.

I would call it a CV personally, and consider "Resume" to be the American-English version, but I'm sure that varies from place to place.

Answer (score 2):

**Generally it is the same, but this is context-dependent**

I had one case where a grant application wanted a CV, defined by them as "a comprehensive listing of everything from awards to employment." I sent my 10-page master resume listing everything back to the last two years of high school and that is apparently what they wanted.

If it is for regular employment, then a resume. Academica might want more as might a grant. A background check could easily want the whole thing.

Comment: A background check won't really rely on the resume, or a CV, by itself. They'll give you a detailed form to fill out. With exact fields to fill out, it's much more obvious when a candidate omits a particular field. Plus on a form, they can ask for contact information as well, and things like names of references and your social security number, plus the permission to do a background check on you.

Answer (score 2):

I generally consider a CV to be a full work/academic history while a Resume is a summary of the most recent/relevant information. I'm sure some other people share the same definitions.

I would generally send a Resume even if asked for a CV because people who read 100's to 1000's of resumes a day don't want to read dozens of pages of boring details dating back to high school or earlier.

If necessary, you can always add some extra text such as "Full CV available at request" that way you if your resume sparks interest, and the recruiter is actually in the market for a full CV, you have essentially provided them a small notification that there are more details you haven't included and its available.

Comment: Most people recommend max 2 or 3 pages for a CV. I have managed to get mine down to 5 or 6, which is the minimum i can give (a full CV would be over twice that length). However, the first page is an executive overview, so you might look at that as a one page resume followed by a 4 or 5 page CV, which they can read or not, as they choose.