# Is it ok to provide a CV when a resume is asked for (US)?

Tags: resume, united-states, applications

I am applying for a new job in the US and the online application form asks for a resume. Is it ok to provide a CV, rather than a resume? (i.e. could it have a negative impact on my application?)

As far as I understand the terms, a 'resume' is typically a single side of paper, whereas a CV is one double-sided page. I prefer to use a CV, as I feel it allows space to provide more details of my past experiences and accomplishments.

Please note that I am asking specifically with regards to the **US** job market. I am aware of this [previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/151944/is-it-fine-to-send-a-resume-instead-of-a-cv); however, it seems to be asking the reverse question and is more focused on Europe.

Comment: I see 3 options: `1.` Convert your CV to a resume and submit that. `2.` Submit your CV and see what happens. `3`. Contact the company and ask them.

Comment: "As far as I understand the terms, a 'resume' is typically a single side of paper, whereas a CV is one double-sided page." I've had no idea that thats a thing, and I worked with a lot of companies across europe and us and just use those terms interchangeably. Did they specify pages limit in ad? If not, send what you think is most fitting. From other side of this experience, the amount of pages varies wildly from 1 to 15 and I never held it against anyone.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul that's how I've always understood those terms - to mean different things. However, you make a good point that the job posting doesn't specify a maximum page limit for the resume.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I find your comment very interesting. In fact, I wonder if that may have even worked against me in the past - that I may have undersold myself by cramming my past experiences into a single side, thinking that is what was being asked for ...

Comment: @Time4Tea can't say, I am no "recruitment specialist" either, I just hire and get hired from time to time. Some jobs post clearly about amount of pages, some don't, some will likely have assumptions about what's sensible and what not, there's no fixed norm I am aware of.  What I know for sure that no matter how many pages you got is that the first one must get attention.

Comment: Just as an aside - I've never heard that anyone differentiated between a CV and a Resume.

Comment: @TheDemonLord I've understood a CV to be a "life history" while a resume is the advertising needed to get in for an interview. Thus, a resume could be significantly shorter and can be customized for each interview one tries to get. Different underlying purposes but often used for the same purpose.

Comment: @DavidR common advice on here seems to be that you customise your CV to each interview (and that you are certainly advertising yourself)

Comment: CV means Curriculum Vitae, it documents your schooling and is used to apply for academic and research positions. Resume documents your work history, with a reference to your degree or schooling at the early end. (don't get me started on 'jealousy' and 'envy'...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## A CV and a US resume are the same thing.

The most you might have to do is alter the CV to reflect American customs, and some of your wording to reflect American English. Other than that, you're fine.

Comment: However, under either name, machine scoring is now A Thing. So for some jobs, keeping it as terse and focused and keyworded as possible may be desirable

Comment: And to expand on this there is no “one page” or “two page” rule.  Make it as short as you can and as long as it needs to be.  Varies based on length of career etc.

Comment: CV focusses on academics, to apply for academic and research positions. So they are not the same or we wouldn't have two terms.

Comment: @HappyIdiot there is no requirement for CVs to focus on academic-focused stuff. The difference in terms is purely regional. The UK uses the term CV for all job applications, whereas the USA uses the term resume. CVs/Resumes are not unique in this regard, there are plenty of things with two (or more!) terms based on regional differences.

Answer (score 4):

A résumé is a summary of achievements. The word literally means summary in English. It's not necessarily one page and many people use it interchangeably with a CV. But in theory it should be briefer, like a summary of the CV.

In your case 2 pages seems fine. Some people cannot summarise their work history etc,. on just one page.

Comment: Most of the resumes I've seen interviewing people for positions in our US-based company are two pages unless we're interviewing someone fresh out of school. More experienced candidates often have three pages.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the field you’re in. If you are applying for a professional job that requires showing more than an “elevator pitch” of your experience such as professional projects, publications, etc. Then I would definitely send your CV. If it’s an entry level or position that doesn’t require much skill then I would stick to a resume. They are definitely different as a therapist I always submit my CV. Now if you would have asked me 10 years ago when I was applying to “regular” jobs it was a simple resume. You could also ask the recruiter what they prefer if possible to get a better idea of what they want.